# Does reversing the order of attributes in the <meta name=robots...> tag affect search engine indexing?

Tags: html, seo, search-engine, meta

Does reversing the attributes in

> < META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW" />

to

> < META CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW" NAME="ROBOTS" />

impair or in any way affect the ability of the search engines to index the page?

Thanks :)

Comment: Not in the slightest.

Answer (score 2):

We can’t possibly know. Search engines may have bugs.

But from the perspective of HTML specifications, no, the attribute order doesn’t affect the meaning.